# Delphi Adicionar linha no SQL erro LIST OF BOUNDS (3)

Tags: sql, delphi

Estou com um problema ao adicionar uma linha no meu SQL  **LIST OF BOUNDS (3)**

```
Delphi :
       clausulaIn := 'AND  A.NNUMEMAPAF IN (0';
      while not Q_Mapas.Eof do
      begin
           clausulaIn := clausulaIn + ',' + IntToStr(Q_MapasNNUMEMAPAF.AsInteger);
      Q_Mapas.next;
      end;

       clausulaIn := clausulaIn + ')';

       qryAgrupaValoresPorData.Close;
       qryAgrupaValoresPorData.SQL[03] := clausulaIn;
       qryAgrupaValoresPorData.ParamByName('EMPRESA').AsInteger := Form_Menu.Q_EmpresasNCODIGOEMPRE.AsInteger;
       qryAgrupaValoresPorData.Open;
```

meu SQL:

```
SELECT A.DDTPGMVFMF DT_PAGTO, SUM(A.NVLPGMVFMF)
  FROM CORMVFMF A
 WHERE A.NCODIGOEMPRE = 2--:EMPRESA
  AND A.NNUMEMAPAF IN (0)
GROUP BY A.DDTPGMVFMF
 ORDER BY A.DDTPGMVFMF
```

Comment: Qual seu problema?

Comment: @Ismael LIST OF BOUNDS (3)

Comment: Veja se é isso (remover o 0): qryAgrupaValoresPorData.SQL[3] := clausulaIn;

Comment: Não resolveu, deu mesmo erro.

Comment: A forma como você está inserindo o SQL está incorreta.
Deve usar uma dessas formas:

    Query.SQL.Add('SQL_A_SER_INSERIDO'); // Adiciona no final
    Query.SQL.Insert(Índice, 'SQL_A_SER_INSERIDO'); // Adiciona na linha desejada

Comment: @WendelRodrigues perdão pela demora é que voltei a mexer no código hoje. Então consegui resolver não sei por qual motivo mais a query estava vazia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, acho que o `SQL` que está no seu componente `qryAgrupaValoresorData` é diferente daquele que você está esperando que esteja lá.

Você espera alterar o conteúdo da quarta linha (a linha de índice 3, já que a contagem começa em 0) pelo conteúdo da variável `clausulaIn`. Tudo parece fazer muito sentido, mas o erro mostra que no `SQL` do componente não existe linha de índice 3.

Se eu estivesse no seu lugar eu daria um debugada e verificaria qual é o conteúdo do SQL do componente e, caso visse que realmente não é aquele que você estava esperando, conferiria o trecho de código que carrega o `SQL` nessa query.

Se for o caso tente colocar um pouco mais informações sobre o caso, talvez eu possa ajudar mais.

Abraço.

Comment: Então eu tinha conseguido resolver, até coloquei no cometario na pergunta. o componente da query estava vazia. Mas Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Dei uma olhada lá nos comentários, vc disse que a query estava vazia. Acho que seria uma boa você colocar porque a query estava vazia e sinalizar como resolvido. Abraço.